# How to use `MathJax mhchem \pu{}` command in LaTex?

Tags: mhchem, mathjax, units

As title says I would like to use `MathJax mhchem \pu{}` command in my LaTeX document. FYI  it is widely used in [chemistry stackexchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) for putting units.

But when used I get the error:

> Undefined control sequence. ... \pu
>
> Missing $ inserted. ...  \pu{ ....
>
> Extra }, or forgotten $. ... \pu{....}

I have included the usepackage command on my preamble:

```
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
```

also tried different versions, all same error. I have also tried putting the `\pu{...}` with and without `$$`.

I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it? maybe you can provide me a working example of `\pu{}` command?

Comment: We will likely need a clue as to what this does: it's not a command from the LaTeX `mhchem` package.

Comment: @JosephWright oh I thought it is a regular command of `MathJax mhchem`! it is widely used in [chemistry stackexchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) for putting units.

Comment: use the siunitx package for typesetting units instead

Answer (score 11):

You cannot. The `\pu` (physical unit) command is a goodie specific to MathJax/mhchem. It is not part of LaTeX/mhchem.

For a LaTeX document, I recommend using the **siunitx** package. With that, you can achieve document-wide consistency of units.

The reasons to add `\pu` to MathJax/mhchem:

- There was (is) no reasonable siunitx implementation for MathJax.
- The concept of centrally defining a style, then using it for the rest of the document is not suited for sites like StackExchange.
- MathJax/mhchem's `\ce` was frequently misused to typeset upright units.
- Reusing the MathJax/mhchem parser and pre-renderer, an implementation of `\pu` was possible with just a few lines of code.

As you see, none of these reasons apply to LaTeX. Therefore, I never considered implementing `\pu` for LaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

I found it used in https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/76935

```
From the above we can see that the first and second coefficients 
in the polynomial fit correspond directly to $A$ and $B$,
respectively. In this example, the energies are in wavenumbers
($\pu{cm^{-1}}$). Most quantum packages print in atomic units
(Hartrees) and dynamics packages print in kJ/mol, which is fine,
but be aware that in the above fit the units are incorporated into
$A$ and $B$.
```

A proper LaTeX setting would be with the `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

From the above we can see that the first and second
coefficients in the polynomial fit correspond directly
to $A$~and~$B$, respectively. In this example, the energies
are in wavenumbers~(\si{\per\centi\meter}). Most quantum
packages print in atomic units (Hartrees) and dynamics
packages print in~\si[per-mode=symbol]{\kilo\joule\per\mol},
which is fine, but be aware that in the above fit the units
are incorporated into $A$~and~$B$.

\bigskip

From the above we can see that the first and second
coefficients in the polynomial fit correspond directly
to $A$~and~$B$, respectively. In this example, the energies
are in wavenumbers~(\si{cm^{-1}}). Most quantum
packages print in atomic units (Hartrees) and dynamics
packages print in~\si{kJ/mol},
which is fine, but be aware that in the above fit the units
are incorporated into $A$~and~$B$.

\end{document}
```

You can directly use representations of the symbols, but it's
much more flexible when names are used.

[image]

Comment: As the author of MathJax/mhchem, I'd recommend `\pu{cm-1}` and `\pu{kJ/mol}` for a chemisty.StackExchange posting.

Comment: There are much nicer examples, like https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86817/24052