# Constructing a command for Physical Dimension - parsing character by character

Tags: mhchem

I wish to have a dedicated command for printing physical dimension. Something like `\phydimen{M2L-3T-1}`. This should output the same as `$\textrm{M}^2\textrm{L}^{-3}\textrm{T}^{-1}$`.

I find that the `\ce` command of `mhchem` package is quite suitable. So I hack it to do `\newcommand{\phydimen}[1]{\ce{#1}}` and then issue a command `\phydimen{ML^2T^{-2}}` to print the dimension. However I still have to use the pesky `^` and `{ }`. The default `\ce` behavior is to push the numbers as subscript.

I want `\phydimen` to automatically detect when a (positive or negative) integer is in the argument and push it to "power". Also `\phydimen` should be able to accept more characters than M,L,T.  Also if lowercase is supplied, it should automatically convert it to uppercase.

How do I parse the arguments character by character and decide whether it is a letter or positive integer or negative integer?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\newcommand{\phydimen}[1]{\ce{#1}}
\begin{document}
    $\textrm{M}^2\textrm{L}^{-3}\textrm{T}^{-1}$ 

    \phydimen{ML^2T^{-2}} % instead I want \phydimen{ML2T-2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\phydimen}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\-?\d+) } { \cU\^\cB\{\1\cE\} } \l_tmpa_tl
  \ensuremath { \mathrm { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\phydimen{ML2T-2}

\end{document}
```

The search expression matches a possibly signed integer, the replacement expression specifies “superscript character, left brace, the match, right brace”.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I wanted. After @mhchem's comment, I was digging regex manipulation of ``l3regex`` to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

Here I use `listofitems` to conduct a 2-tier parsing, looking for digits at the first level and for the `negative` sign at the second level.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\phydimen[1]{%
  \setsepchar{0||1||2||3||4||5||6||7||8||9/-}%
  \greadlist\Dim{#1}%
  \foreachitem\i\in\Dim{%
    \textrm{\Dim[\icnt,1]}\ensuremath{^{\Dimsep[\icnt,1]\Dimsep[\icnt]}}}%
}
\begin{document}
\phydimen{ML2T-2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Parsing letter by letter is a complicated thing in LaTeX. You could open mhchem.sty and look how this is done. Or see [Basics of parsing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233085/73371) or [How can I parse the first word in a token stream, token by token?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150909).

I would not recommend using `\ce` inside your command. It does way more stuff than just changing the font. It would double-parse the input, I think this will not be efficient.

The command you want to create already exists within mhchem for MathJax. Why it does not exist for LaTeX is explained in the question [How to use `MathJax mhchem \pu{}` command in LaTex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/405579), including reasons to use another command instead.